# DialogFragment in Fragment and callbacks

Tags: android

I have read a lot of documents about how to use fragments but I have one more doubt.
I have one activity that controls 3 fragments, now in one of this fragment I call a DialogFragment and following the google's tutorial I defined an interface to the activity for callbacks. All it's works properly but is this the only way to pass data to the fragment that fired the Dialog? I think that it would be more convenient passing data directly to the  fragment instead of passing from the activity. is there any method to do this?
Thank you in advance.